# Apache httpd.conf configuration. Permission issue

Tags: apache

I have written htaccess rules for rewrites. I am fairly sure that the rules are correct. For this I also made changes to httpd.conf to 'allow all' but when I try to access from browser I get this error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

I am running Apache 2.2.29 on Amazon server.

Here is my htaccess file with the edits that I have already done to it:

```
 # Don't give away too much information about all the subcomponents
    # we are running.  Comment out this line if you don't mind remote sites
    # finding out what major optional modules you are running
    ServerTokens OS


    # Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
    #
    ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

    #
    # PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
    # identification number when it starts.  Note the PIDFILE variable in
    # /etc/sysconfig/httpd must be set appropriately if this location is
    # changed.
    #
    PidFile run/httpd.pid

    #
    # Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
    #
    Timeout 60

    #
    # KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
    # one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
    #
    KeepAlive Off


    MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

    #
    # KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
    # same client on the same connection.
    #
    KeepAliveTimeout 15

    ##
    ## Server-Pool Size Regulation (MPM specific)
    ## 

    <IfModule prefork.c>
    StartServers       8
    MinSpareServers    5
    MaxSpareServers   20
    ServerLimit      256
    MaxClients       256
    MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule worker.c>
    StartServers         4
    MaxClients         300
    MinSpareThreads     25
    MaxSpareThreads     75 
    ThreadsPerChild     25
    MaxRequestsPerChild  0
    </IfModule>

    #
    # Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
    # ports, in addition to the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
    # directive.
    #
    # Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
    # prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses (0.0.0.0)
    #
    #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
    Listen 80


    #
    # Example:
    # LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
    #
    LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
    LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
    LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
    LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
    LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
    LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
    LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
    LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
    LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
    LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
    LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
    LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
    LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
    LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
    LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
    LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
    LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
    LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
    LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
    LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
    LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
    LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
    LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
    LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
    LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
    LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
    LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
    LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
    LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
    LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
    LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
    LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
    LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
    LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
    LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
    LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
    LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
    LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
    LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
    LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
    LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
    LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
    LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
    LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
    LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
    LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
    LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
    LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
    LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
    LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
    LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
    LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so

    #
    # The following modules are not loaded by default:
    #
    #LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
    #LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
    #LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
    #LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
    #LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
    #LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
    #LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
    #LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
    #LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
    #LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
    #LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
    #

    #
    # Load config files from the config directory "/etc/httpd/conf.d".
    #
    Include conf.d/*.conf


    #ExtendedStatus On


    #
    User apache
    Group apache

    #
    ServerAdmin root@localhost


    #
    #ServerName www.example.com:80

    #

    #
    UseCanonicalName Off

    #
    # DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
    # documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
    # symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
    #
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

    #

    #
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    #
    # Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
    # particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
    # you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
    # below.
    #

    #
    # This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
    #
    <Directory "/var/www/html">

    #

    #
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
        AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

    </Directory>

    #

    # See also: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/misc/FAQ.html#forbidden
    #
    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        #
        # UserDir is disabled by default since it can confirm the presence
        # of a username on the system (depending on home directory
        # permissions).
        #
        UserDir disabled

        #
        # To enable requests to /~user/ to serve the user's public_html
        # directory, remove the "UserDir disabled" line above, and uncomment
        # the following line instead:
        # 
        #UserDir public_html

    </IfModule>

    #
    # Control access to UserDir directories.  The following is an example
    # for a site where these directories are restricted to read-only.
    #
    #<Directory /home/*/public_html>
    #    AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
    #    <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
    #        Order allow,deny
    #        Allow from all
    #    </Limit>
    #    <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
    #        Order deny,allow
    #        Deny from all
    #    </LimitExcept>
    #</Directory>

    #

    #
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var

    #
    # AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
    # for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
    # directive.
    #
    AccessFileName .htaccess

    #
    # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
    # viewed by Web clients. 
    #
    <Files ~ "^\.ht">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
        Satisfy All
    </Files>

    #
    # TypesConfig describes where the mime.types file (or equivalent) is
    # to be found.
    #
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    #

    #
    DefaultType text/plain

    #
    # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
    # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
    # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
    #
    <IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>
    #   MIMEMagicFile /usr/share/magic.mime
        MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
    </IfModule>

    #

    #
    HostnameLookups Off

    #
    # EnableMMAP: Control whether memory-mapping is used to deliver
    # files (assuming that the underlying OS supports it).
    # The default is on; turn this off if you serve from NFS-mounted 
    # filesystems.  On some systems, turning it off (regardless of
    # filesystem) can improve performance; for details, please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#enablemmap
    #
    #EnableMMAP off

    #
    # EnableSendfile: Control whether the sendfile kernel support is 
    # used to deliver files (assuming that the OS supports it). 
    # The default is on; turn this off if you serve from NFS-mounted 
    # filesystems.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#enablesendfile
    #
    #EnableSendfile off

    #

    #
    ErrorLog logs/error_log

    #
    # LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    #
    LogLevel warn

    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
    LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

    # "combinedio" includes actual counts of actual bytes received (%I) and sent (%O); this
    # requires the mod_logio module to be loaded.
    #LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio

    #

    #
    #CustomLog logs/access_log common

    #
    # If you would like to have separate agent and referer logfiles, uncomment
    # the following directives.
    #
    #CustomLog logs/referer_log referer
    #CustomLog logs/agent_log agent

    #
    # For a single logfile with access, agent, and referer information
    # (Combined Logfile Format), use the following directive:
    #
    CustomLog logs/access_log combined

    #

    #
    ServerSignature On

    #

    #
    # We include the /icons/ alias for FancyIndexed directory listings.  If you
    # do not use FancyIndexing, you may comment this out.
    #
    Alias /icons/ "/var/www/icons/"

    <Directory "/var/www/icons">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    #
    # WebDAV module configuration section.
    # 
    <IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
        # Location of the WebDAV lock database.
        DAVLockDB /var/lib/dav/lockdb
    </IfModule>

    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts.
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the realname directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the client.
    # The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias directives as to
    # Alias.
    #
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

    #
    # "/var/www/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
    # CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
    #
    <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    #
    # Redirect allows you to tell clients about documents which used to exist in
    # your server's namespace, but do not anymore. This allows you to tell the
    # clients where to look for the relocated document.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

    #
    # Directives controlling the display of server-generated directory listings.
    #

    #
    # IndexOptions: Controls the appearance of server-generated directory
    # listings.
    #
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HTMLTable Charset=UTF-8

    #
    # AddIcon* directives tell the server which icon to show for different
    # files or filename extensions.  These are only displayed for
    # FancyIndexed directories.
    #
    AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compress x-gzip

    AddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*
    AddIconByType (IMG,/icons/image2.gif) image/*
    AddIconByType (SND,/icons/sound2.gif) audio/*
    AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*

    AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exe
    AddIcon /icons/binhex.gif .hqx
    AddIcon /icons/tar.gif .tar
    AddIcon /icons/world2.gif .wrl .wrl.gz .vrml .vrm .iv
    AddIcon /icons/compressed.gif .Z .z .tgz .gz .zip
    AddIcon /icons/a.gif .ps .ai .eps
    AddIcon /icons/layout.gif .html .shtml .htm .pdf
    AddIcon /icons/text.gif .txt
    AddIcon /icons/c.gif .c
    AddIcon /icons/p.gif .pl .py
    AddIcon /icons/f.gif .for
    AddIcon /icons/dvi.gif .dvi
    AddIcon /icons/uuencoded.gif .uu
    AddIcon /icons/script.gif .conf .sh .shar .csh .ksh .tcl
    AddIcon /icons/tex.gif .tex
    AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif core

    AddIcon /icons/back.gif ..
    AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif README
    AddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^
    AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^

    #
    # DefaultIcon is which icon to show for files which do not have an icon
    # explicitly set.
    #
    DefaultIcon /icons/unknown.gif

    #
    # AddDescription allows you to place a short description after a file in
    # server-generated indexes.  These are only displayed for FancyIndexed
    # directories.
    # Format: AddDescription "description" filename
    #
    #AddDescription "GZIP compressed document" .gz
    #AddDescription "tar archive" .tar
    #AddDescription "GZIP compressed tar archive" .tgz

    #
    # ReadmeName is the name of the README file the server will look for by
    # default, and append to directory listings.
    #
    # HeaderName is the name of a file which should be prepended to
    # directory indexes. 
    ReadmeName README.html
    HeaderName HEADER.html

    #
    # IndexIgnore is a set of filenames which directory indexing should ignore
    # and not include in the listing.  Shell-style wildcarding is permitted.
    #
    IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t

    #

    #
    AddLanguage ca .ca
    AddLanguage cs .cz .cs
    AddLanguage da .dk
    AddLanguage de .de
    AddLanguage el .el
    AddLanguage en .en
    AddLanguage eo .eo
    AddLanguage es .es
    AddLanguage et .et
    AddLanguage fr .fr
    AddLanguage he .he
    AddLanguage hr .hr
    AddLanguage it .it
    AddLanguage ja .ja
    AddLanguage ko .ko
    AddLanguage ltz .ltz
    AddLanguage nl .nl
    AddLanguage nn .nn
    AddLanguage no .no
    AddLanguage pl .po
    AddLanguage pt .pt
    AddLanguage pt-BR .pt-br
    AddLanguage ru .ru
    AddLanguage sv .sv
    AddLanguage zh-CN .zh-cn
    AddLanguage zh-TW .zh-tw

    #
    # LanguagePriority allows you to give precedence to some languages
    # in case of a tie during content negotiation.
    #
    # Just list the languages in decreasing order of preference. We have
    # more or less alphabetized them here. You probably want to change this.
    #
    LanguagePriority en ca cs da de el eo es et fr he hr it ja ko ltz nl nn no pl pt pt-BR ru sv zh-CN zh-TW

    #
    # ForceLanguagePriority allows you to serve a result page rather than
    # MULTIPLE CHOICES (Prefer) [in case of a tie] or NOT ACCEPTABLE (Fallback)
    # [in case no accepted languages matched the available variants]
    #
    ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback

    #
    # Specify a default charset for all content served; this enables
    # interpretation of all content as UTF-8 by default.  To use the 
    # default browser choice (ISO-8859-1), or to allow the META tags
    # in HTML content to override this choice, comment out this
    # directive:
    #
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file mime.types for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-tar .tgz

    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    # Despite the name similarity, the following Add* directives have nothing
    # to do with the FancyIndexing customization directives above.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz

    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    #
    #   MIME-types for downloading Certificates and CRLs
    #
    AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
    AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl

    #
    # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
    # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
    # or added with the Action directive (see below)
    #
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

    #
    # For files that include their own HTTP headers:
    #
    #AddHandler send-as-is asis

    #
    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    # (This is enabled by default to allow the Apache "It Worked" page
    #  to be distributed in multiple languages.)
    #
    AddHandler type-map var

    #
    # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
    #
    # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml

    #
    # Action lets you define media types that will execute a script whenever
    # a matching file is called. This eliminates the need for repeated URL
    # pathnames for oft-used CGI file processors.
    # Format: Action media/type /cgi-script/location
    # Format: Action handler-name /cgi-script/location
    #

    #
    # Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
    # 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
    #
    # Some examples:
    #ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
    #ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
    #ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
    #ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
    #

    #

    #

    Alias /error/ "/var/www/error/"

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    <IfModule mod_include.c>
        <Directory "/var/www/error">
            AllowOverride None
            Options IncludesNoExec
            AddOutputFilter Includes html
            AddHandler type-map var
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            LanguagePriority en es de fr
            ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
        </Directory>

    #    ErrorDocument 400 /error/HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 401 /error/HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 404 /error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 405 /error/HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 408 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_TIME_OUT.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 410 /error/HTTP_GONE.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 411 /error/HTTP_LENGTH_REQUIRED.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 412 /error/HTTP_PRECONDITION_FAILED.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 413 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 414 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_URI_TOO_LARGE.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 415 /error/HTTP_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 500 /error/HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 501 /error/HTTP_NOT_IMPLEMENTED.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 502 /error/HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 503 /error/HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 506 /error/HTTP_VARIANT_ALSO_VARIES.html.var

    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The following directives modify normal HTTP response behavior to
    # handle known problems with browser implementations.
    #
    BrowserMatch "Mozilla/2" nokeepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE 4\.0b2;" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "RealPlayer 4\.0" force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "Java/1\.0" force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "JDK/1\.0" force-response-1.0

    #
    # The following directive disables redirects on non-GET requests for
    # a directory that does not include the trailing slash.  This fixes a 
    # problem with Microsoft WebFolders which does not appropriately handle 
    # redirects for folders with DAV methods.
    # Same deal with Apple's DAV filesystem and Gnome VFS support for DAV.
    #
    BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "MS FrontPage" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[0123]" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "^gnome-vfs/1.0" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "^XML Spy" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-carefully

    #
    # Allow server status reports generated by mod_status,
    # with the URL of http://servername/server-status
    # Change the ".example.com" to match your domain to enable.
    #
    #<Location /server-status>
    #    SetHandler server-status
    #    Order deny,allow
    #    Deny from all
    #    Allow from .example.com
    #</Location>

    #
    # Allow remote server configuration reports, with the URL of
    #  http://servername/server-info (requires that mod_info.c be loaded).
    # Change the ".example.com" to match your domain to enable.
    #
    #<Location /server-info>
    #    SetHandler server-info
    #    Order deny,allow
    #    Deny from all
    #    Allow from .example.com
    #</Location>

    #
    # Proxy Server directives. Uncomment the following lines to
    # enable the proxy server:
    #
    #<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    #ProxyRequests On
    #
    #<Proxy *>
    #    Order deny,allow
    #    Deny from all
    #    Allow from .example.com
    #</Proxy>

    #
    # Enable/disable the handling of HTTP/1.1 "Via:" headers.
    # ("Full" adds the server version; "Block" removes all outgoing Via: headers)
    # Set to one of: Off | On | Full | Block
    #
    #ProxyVia On

    #
    # To enable a cache of proxied content, uncomment the following lines.
    # See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cache.html for more details.
    #
    #<IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
    #   CacheEnable disk /
    #   CacheRoot "/var/cache/mod_proxy"
    #</IfModule>
    #

    #</IfModule>
    # End of proxy directives.

    ### Section 3: Virtual Hosts
    #

    # You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
    # configuration.

    #
    # Use name-based virtual hosting.
    #
    #NameVirtualHost *:80
    #
    # NOTE: NameVirtualHost cannot be used without a port specifier 
    # (e.g. :80) if mod_ssl is being used, due to the nature of the
    # SSL protocol.
    #

    #
    # VirtualHost example:
    # Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
    # The first VirtualHost section is used for requests without a known
    # server name.
    #
    #<VirtualHost *:80>
    #    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    #    DocumentRoot /www/docs/dummy-host.example.com
    #    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    #    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
    #    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
    #</VirtualHost>
```

(I have removed many comments in the file due to length limit)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't have any configurations in your other *.conf files that might be conflicting.  Also make sure that the user that your web server is running as has access to `/var/www/html`

try this for the `/` path as well then restart your Apache server:

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

You also want to verify that your server has an [`.htaccess`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) file in `/var/www/html`.  Or if you want to disable `.htaccess` files then change `AllowOverride All` in the above block to `AllowOverride None`. After you save those changes restart your server and try again.

Comment: Updated my answer with a configuration change to try.

Comment: updated my answer.  You will also want to double check that your `/var/www/html` folder has an `.htaccess` file or if you don't have one and want to disable `.htaccess` files then change `AllowOverride All` to `AllowOverride None`. Then restart your server.